# How can you skip a loop iteration in python if a function called inside the loop takes too long to execute?

Tags: python

I want to loop over a set of files and perform an operation on each of them which is specified in "runthingy()". However, because this operation gets stuck on some of those files stopping the entire program, i want to skip this particular file if it takes longer than 120 seconds to complete. I am using Windows which is why signal.SIGALARM is not available, so I am using the stopit library (https://pypi.org/project/stopit/) instead. The following example code will abort the while loop and print timeout after 3 seconds:

```
with stopit.ThreadingTimeout(3) as to_ctx_mrg:
    while(True):
        continue


if to_ctx_mrg.state == to_ctx_mrg.TIMED_OUT:
        print("Time out")
```

However, using it in this context will never print out time out if the runthingy() function gets stuck/takes forever to complete:

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"\\files\\"):
    with stopit.ThreadingTimeout(120) as to_ctx_mrg:
        runthingy(filename)
    if to_ctx_mrg.state == to_ctx_mrg.TIMED_OUT:
        print("Time out")
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience of the library you are using but it says it raises an asynchronous exception in the timed out thread.

The question is why your function gets 'stuck'?  The Python interpreter will only detect that an exception has been raised when it is interpreting Python instructions within that thread. If the reason your function sticks is that it has made a C call that hasn't returned then other Python threads can still probably run, but they won't be able to interrupt the remote thread.

You need to look more closely at why 'runthingy()' blocks. Is it perhaps reading from a socket, or waiting for a file lock? If the call that blocks has an optional timeout then make sure the timeout parameter is set fairly low: even if the code just retries the call after a timeout it at least gives the Python interpreter a chance to get in there and abort the process.

Better still, if you can find out why the function sticks you may be able to fix the underlying problem instead of applying a brute force timeout.